# Search for a value in a two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to compare a number to a dimensional array. I think that my problem is here, but I dont know why it cannot compile because of this.

```
if(a[j].equals(numb)){
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because a[j][i] is int and no Integer, it means that you can't compare it with `.equals()` since it is a primitive type, you have to use `==`

Furthermore, you are comparing a[j] with an int but a[j] is an array, you have to access its int with double [][] : `a[i][j]`

Comment: ooh wait...I changed also the a[i][j]...then it worked.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just write `a[j] == numb` ? Since a[j] and numb are both integers, that should work just fine. `equals()` is a method for objects, which you could call for `Integers` for instance, but not for `ints`.

Comment: i am kind of new, I want to compare "numb" to all of my arrays, and if have the same value, print the value, if not print -1. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, the rest of your code does look correct i think, it should do what you want it to do. Try it with == instead of equals, i hope that solves your problem.

Comment: also, I had to change a[i][j]...Thanks

Comment: yeah, i saw it too, after it was mentioned :) youre welcome.